# Building Docker Images with heroku.yml (failed to bind to port)

Tags: node.js, docker, express, heroku

my Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
copy . /app

# Expose 9000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web:
       Dockerfile
```

index.js contains (using express)

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;
const HOST = "localhost";
app.listen(PORT,HOST, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

After `git push heroku master` the web process failing to bind after 1 minute of starting.
How can i resolve this ?

```
listening on port 25941
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
Process exited with status 137
State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some reading on Heroku, it seems it specifies a random port. It also says [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime) that Dockerfile EXPOSE is not respected.

I'd guess the problem is with HOST:

```
const HOST = "localhost";
app.listen(PORT,HOST, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

The HOST parameter can be omitted and just the callback can be passed instead:

```
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: It worked.  I am wondering how docker is able to expose a port (allocated by heroku) without exposing it explicitly.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-multiple-images You use herokus CLI to build the image: `heroku container:push --recursive`, my guess is that the CLI takes care of the mapping and adding the correct port to the EXPOSE directive. If you were doing `docker build ...` yourself and it would've worked, I'd be very confused myself :)